# Disable the overheat guard of the cpu (Sensor defect)

Tags: cpu, desktop, fan, cooling, temperature

So I think that my CPU sensor is defect, let me explain why. The pc is shutting down instantly, even in idle. Some programs like speedfan show that my cpu has more than 80°C . It has a really big tower cooler so the cooler shouldn't be a problem and it is clean! The thermal paste looks fine to me, I could try to put new one, but I think that the sensor is kinda destroyed. I put my finger on the cpu to feel the temperatur right after the pc shuted down, and it was cool.

Now I would really like to know if there is a possibility to disable the overheat guard thing on my cpu?

I have a picture of the heat paste, but I need 10 reputation to post it...

Comment: Is the cooler plugged into the motherboard on the pin array labeled CPU_FAN? Some motherboards won't boot or respond oddly if no current is being drawn from those pins, because they assume that no heatsink fan is installed. Also with large heatsinks, in tower boxes, gravity will slowly pull the heatsink surface away from the CPU die just due to the weight and mounting profile, so it really seems like you should take it off and remount it with new thermal paste. Finally no you cannot disable the CPUs thermal protections on the chip itself. most intel chips will shut off when it reaches TJMAX.

Comment: The Pc is starting and running for some minutes, half an hour or so then shutting down, and I have the mainboard at this moment on my desk so the heat sink is over the cpu and gravity presses it down on the cpu. I remounted it too, but I have first to buy new themal paste to put some new one on.

Comment: And yes it is plugged in into CPU-FAN, it is running

Comment: I think I should feel some heat at the heat pipes or even one the cpu itself, but it is all cool.

Comment: well, the Intel sensor that shuts you down may be malfunctioning, but it is in hardware and cannot be disabled on a consumer system. If you have truely eliminated all the actual  thermal possibilities, then you are probably going to have to replace it.

Comment: okay it seems that something has changed, afer I remounted it now again, I startet prime95 and it is running smoothly for more than 15 minutes at 100% cpu with 33°C, the strange part was, that the temperature dropped as the program started...

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or something but the temperature keeps rising again when the program is turned off and cpu is in idle.

Comment: weird. have you done a motherboard firmware (BIOS flash) or Intel Chipset driver update lately? if not, perhaps you should. you aren't overclocking or doing anything weird with CPU throttling settings (control panel power settings) are you? if you use alternative tools like CPUTemp or CPUZ in addition to speedfan, do they all read the same?